# How does this manipulation of summation of exponents work?

Tags: machine-learning, arithmetic, sum

I found this paper by Fischer and Igel (2012) (1).

I am not able to get past this last step in their derivations (eqn 22, p24)

[image]

where $h_i$ are values of $h$. Can anyone tell me how they reduced the summation to $1 + \exp(...)$?

(1) Fischer, A. and Igel, C. (2012),
"An Introduction to Restricted Boltzmann Machines",
(from L. Alvarez et al. (Eds.): CIARP 2012, LNCS 7441, pp. 14–36)
http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf

Comment: From the paper it seems to me that each $h_i$ takes only 2 values: 0 and 1, so that sum consists only of those two elements.

Comment: The solution is evident in the part of equation (22) you did not reproduce: the right hand side is the product of sums of the form $$\sum_{h_i=0}^1 e^{h_i(\cdots)} = 1 + e^{(\cdots)}.$$

Comment: I see. so hi is only 0 or 1. Then its obvious how they got the next step. I missed that part. Thanks to both of you.